# mod_rewrite part of the query string

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a situation with opencart where I need to rewrite only the "route" leaving other query strings as it is.  Example:

```
http://www.example.com/?route=module/ext/products&category_id=15&sort=newest
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/ext/products?category_id=15&sort=newest
```

how can I do that?

---

**UPDATE:** I have some constraints. This rewrite condition should only be applied to `route=module/ecomapi/([^&]+)`. Not for other routes.

```
RewriteRule ^ecomapi/21/(products)/([^?]*)$ index.php?route=module/ecomapi/$1&product_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ecomapi/21/(login)/([^?]*)$ index.php?route=module/ecomapi/$1&email=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ecomapi/21/(users)/([^?]*)$ index.php?route=module/ecomapi/$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ecomapi/21/(products|navigation_drawer|banners|cart|login|d‌​evices|shops)?$ index.php?route=module/ecomapi/$1 [B,L,QSA]
```

Comment: There is a duplicate question on Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539981/htaccess-301-redirect-rule-to-remove-part-of-a-query-string-from-urls-but-leave

Comment: You need to clarify exactly how one URL maps to the other... since your example is doing more than just "rewrite only the "route" leaving other query strings as it is". It looks like you are extracting part of the `route` URL param (everything after `module/`?) and using this in the URL-path? Is the `route` URL param always first in the query string? Is it for this single URL or do you need a general solution? Can you clarify whether you mean a "rewrite" or an "external redirect"?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file (or server config):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=module/([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1?%2 [R,L]
```

This makes the following assumptions:

- An *external redirect* (302 - temporary). (Change the `R` flag to `R=301` to make it permanent.)
- Only an initial request for the document root is considered.
- The `route` URL param always exists at the *start* of the query string.
- Everything after `module/` in the `route` URL param value is extracted to form the URL-path in the *substitution*.
- There must be *something* after `module/`. But this "something" could be *anything*. (You should probably be as explicit as possible here in order to prevent matching against wholly invalid URL-paths.)
- The `route` URL parameter could be the only URL param.

Comment: Thanks .  This works fine.  But I have some constraints.  This rewrite condition should  be only to "route=module/ecomapi/([^&]+)".  Not for other routes   RewriteRule ^ecomapi/21/(products)/([^?]*)$ index.php?route=module/ecomapi/$1&product_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ecomapi/21/(login)/([^?]*)$ index.php?route=module/ecomapi/$1&email=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ecomapi/21/(users)/([^?]*)$ index.php?route=module/ecomapi/$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ecomapi/21/(products|navigation_drawer|banners|cart|login|devices|shops)?$ index.php?route=module/ecomapi/$1 [B,L,QSA]

Comment: But I think there should be a better way to simplify

Comment: Presumably you've just modified the `RewriteCond` directive for the route that it should apply to, and that works OK? I don't see how those other directives can be simplified further (or better) - these would seem to be required for your application to work correctly. (?)